# Objective-C block property access crashes after app switching

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, block

I have created a wrapper for the FBConnect iOS SDK that declares a block property for performing some code after successful login. Relevant code is as follows:

```
typedef void(^FacebookServiceLoginBlock)(BOOL loginSuccessful);

@interface FacebookService : NSObject <FBSessionDelegate,FBRequestDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, copy) FacebookServiceLoginBlock loginBlock;
- (void) checkAuthorization:(FacebookServiceLoginBlock)loginBlock;
@end


@implementation FacebookService
@synthesize loginBlock;


- (void) checkAuthorization:(FacebookServiceLoginBlock)block {
    if (![self.facebook isSessionValid]) {
        self.loginBlock = block;

        // do Facebook auth
    } else {
        if (block) {
            block(YES);
        }
    }
}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[self.facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[self.facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    self.loginBlock(YES);
}
```

The calling code just invokes the **checkAuthentication** method with a block that does basically nothing, just one int `i=0;` line so I can add a breakpoint. In the event that the user is already logged in and the block is invoked immediately, things work fine. However, if FB auth happens and the app switches to Safari or the FB app to authorize, upon returning, when the FB login success delegate is invoked, the app crashes on `self.loginBlock(YES)`; If I wrap it in an if(`self.loginBlock`), it gets skipped, leading me to believe that the property is nil, but if I print description in the debugger, it evaluates to the name of the class "**FacebookService**". Other relevant note, this is under ARC.

I'm really stumped on this one, any help would be great.

Comment: Not sure if this is the complete answer to your issue, but your typedef declaration is incorrect for that block. You don't put the named parameter in there just the type; it should be: typedef void(^FacebookServiceLoginBlock)(BOOL);

Comment: @afrederick: Either way is valid syntax, and including a named parameter helps readability.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Interesting I've never seen it that way, I'll have to adopt it

Answer (score 0):

A few hours after posting this it dawned on me what the issue is. I am using a different instance of FacebookService from the context where I launch the login to where the openURL message is responded to. I am going to change things to only one instance and things will be fine.